# What is "inclusive" mode in the mongo aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am playing around with the mongo aggregation framework, and I can not at all figure out some of the terminology. Most particularly, in some of the examples the reference $project being in "inclusive mode". I have also heard of _id being selected "implicity" in related contexts. Can anyone clarify?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/project/

```
db.article.aggregate(
    { $project : {
        title : 1 ,
        stats : {
            pv : "$pageViews",
            foo : "$other.foo",
            dpv : { $add:["$pageViews", 10] }
        }
    }}
);


This projection includes the title field and places $project into “inclusive” mode. Then, it creates the stats documents with the following fields:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> _id being selected "implicity"

When you making projections, you have to specify all field explicitly:

```
> db.a.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51c8744a1c0a41d783d77431"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3 }
> db.a.aggregate({$project:{a:1}})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("51c8744a1c0a41d783d77431"),
            "a" : 1
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Here you include only 'a' in result document, all other fields was dropped. The only difference is **_id** field, which is always included, but you can explicitly turn it off:

```
> db.a.aggregate({$project:{a:1, _id:0}})
{ "result" : [ { "a" : 1 } ], "ok" : 1 }
```

> $project being in "inclusive mode"

This is simple: if you want some field to be included in result document **as-is**, you can just type somethig like **{a:1}**, it just shortcut to saying **{a:'$a'}**